# Как отправлять данные из php скрипта подключенного через ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется страница на которую подключаю с помощью Ajax php страницу с формами и отправкой некоторых данных в базу. Проблем с подключением нет, но есть проблема с отправкой данных. Если отправлять данные напрямую со страницы скрипта, то все работает, но если отправлять данные со страницы на которую идет Ajax вывод, то  при отправке страница просто обновляется и не отправляет данные в базу.
Вот подключение к странице:

```
$(function(e) {
  $('#edit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'profiles/file.php',
      success: function(data) {
             $('#result').html(data);
  }
});
});
});
```

Думаю с php частью и так все понятно, все по дефолту.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас `#edit` кнопка в форме или ссылка, то страница будет перезагружаться, т. к. у вас функция не возвращает `false`. Так же вы не отправляете никаких данных в этом запросе.

```
$(function(e) {
  $('#edit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'profiles/file.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {"key": "value"}
      success: function(data) {
             $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: По кнопке  #edit происходит вывод файла в блок #result на странице. Данные я отправляю через неё (страницу на которую пришел файл). Т.е если зайти непосредственно на file.php, то данные отправятся. Но при Ajax выводе, данные будто не успевают обработаться.

Comment: А в консоле браузера что-нибудь выводится или посмотреть вкладку `Network` в инструментах разработчика.

Comment: Вообще ничего не выводится

Comment: Вы уверены, что `click` на кнопку отрабатывает?

Comment: Ну файл же выводится по клику на кнопку.